# Multi-master data replication across different AWS regions

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, cloud, distributed-system, distributed-transactions

We need to synchronize data stored in different AWS regions that may reside on different databases(MySQL, Postgres, DynamoDB etc.). For example, we may have a user that has a profile in both us-east-1 and us-west-2 and her data may be stored in MySQL on us-east-1 and on Postgres in us-west-2. Because we use geoDNS to route user requests, her changes could end up writing databases in any AWS region. What we'd like to see is for her changes to propagate to all regions eventually.

Our current stack is mostly cloud-native on Kubernetes and AWS. Is there a good way to accomplish this in a cloud-native manner?

My current intuition is to use Kafka and Kafka connectors into different databases to listen for changes and apply them to different regions in the same order. The problem I can see with this approach are:

1. This relies on a single master partition that all databases in different regions will have to write to. I understand that this is necessary to guarantee ordering but isn't this a single point of failure?
2. Do we make local database changes visible to a specific region's users immediately after write or do we have them write to Kafka and let the local database catch up to Kafka's log of changes? In other words, during a write to say us-east-1, do we wait for the us-east-1 database to catch up to all Kafka changes before letting it write to the database? Or do we only write to Kafka indicating a change and let another process asynchronously apply changes to the us-east-1 database as well?